# Interpretation of the hazard rate and the probability density function

Tags: survival, density-function, hazard

The books of survival analysis state that

$f(t) = \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(t < T \leq t + \Delta t)}{\Delta t} $

$h(t) = \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(t < T \leq t + \Delta t|T \geq t)}{\Delta t} = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$

I know $h(t)$ is a conditional probability and commonly used to describe the failure.
But $f(t)$ is also a metric of failure.
Can we use it to describe the failure?
If yes, what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `f(t)` (or really, the expectation of `f(t)`) as life expectancy at birth - the only condition is that the subject is alive at time `T = 0`. `f(t)` can be very useful, it is the distribution of failure times.

`h(t)`, however, is often more interesting. As someone who has lived quite a few years past birth already, `f(t)` seems less useful whereas `h(t)` has *immediate* relevance.

From a modeling perspective, `h(t)` lends itself nicely to comparisons between different groups. In a hazard models, we can model the hazard rate of one group as some multiplier times the hazard rate of another group. With Cox Proportional Hazards we can even skip the estimation of the `h(t)` altogether and *just* estimate the ratios.

Of course, this will result in different `f(t)` distributions for the groups, but whereas this multiplier is a convenient way to summarize the differences between groups both in a model and in communication, I wouldn't know how to summarize the resulting `f(t)` distributions of the two groups other than to plot them. While one group's hazard rate can always be twice that of another group, no such simple construction will work for `f(t)` since `f(t)` must always integrate to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain "the only condition is that the subject is alive at time T = 0". I don't understand this point. Is there any subject not alive at time T = 0?

Comment: That's exactly the point. And it's to contrast with `h(t)` which, at every time `t` is conditional on subjects being alive at time `t`. Those which have already failed are no longer considered.

Comment: Yeah, I have understood your opinion of the condictional possibility. I have a new idea about the difference of the two functions. The f(t) is a distribution of failure times. It only covers failed items. When using the Kaplan-Meier method, the h(t) is able to cover all items including the left truncated items (not observes from age 0) and the right censored items (not fails by the end of study). But there is no method enabling the f(t) to cover normal items. Thus, we use h(t) more often than the f(t). Is this a correct idea?

Comment: One more thing. Kaplan-Meier method is a non-parametric maximum likelihood estimate of the survival function `S(t)`. May I use the `S(t)` to derive the `h(t)`? Is this `h(t)` a suitable random variable to estimate the hazard rate?

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "no method enabling f(t) to cover normal items". Indeed, left-censored observations are difficult to incorporate into `f(t)` estimates - I don't know much about that. I'm sure you also know that 'S(t)` is defined as $1  - \int_0^t f(x) dx$, so if you know S(t) or f(t) you can easily know h(t) as well - theoretically. In practice you only have information about the hazard rate at the times when failures are observed. So you can estimate the hazard rate at those times and smooth those points to interpolate a continuous hazard rate.

Comment: There's also, of course, the Nelson-Aalen estimator which is similar to Kaplan-Meier but estimates the cumulative hazard.

Comment: "no method enabling f(t) to cover normal items" can be explained that when we calculate `f(t)`, we only use mean time to fail of the failed/dead items and neglect the normal/alive items. `h(t)` conducted from this `f(t)` also contains failed items only. But Kaplan-Meier estimator `S(t)` enables the left and right censored items. `h(t)` conducted from the `S(t)` contains the normal items.

Comment: Well, if you're calculating the **mean** time of failure then you are trying to calculate $E(f(t))$, not $f(t)$. And yes, if you ignore censored observations then you are doing a crummy job of it.